# Reapplying for UK Standard Visa after refusal due to Incorrect details

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals

My Visitor visa is refused due to a big blunder I have made while filling the application, which I have realised only after being pointed by a friend. I have mentioned my annual income as monthly income. Ofcourse, it didn't match with any of the financial documents I have provided. That's it case is gone.

It also might have appeared that I'm trying to cheat !

Background :

I planned to visit UK for a cycling event.My relative staying there has provided me a welcome letter, his passport copy and council tax copy. I have provided them Invitation letter from event organisers, Employment letter, pay slips for six months, account statements of My salary account, savings account in another bank, travel Insurance, my flight tickets, and letter provided by relative and rental agreement in India. I thought they will be sufficient for a visitor visa.

My wife will join me after my cycling event is completed. So I have provided her bank account statement, her flight tickets also.I haven't provided any marriage certificate.

In my savings account, there is money, with drawn from my mutual funds, wife's savings and the amount I saved from my salary account.

You can see comments regarding them all in the refusal letter below. Also, I haven't mentioned much about my cycling.

Now since, I have realised my mistake and this event being very important to me, as I'm practising past 2 years for it...I'm planning to apply again on a 1 week priority basis. Here is what I'm planning to do and  my queries.

1. I'm filling application *very carefully* and providing my bank account statements again, with a letter to explain that the deposits are from my funds and from wife. Will provide mutual funds statements also, along with wife's employment letter, pay slips, account statement and her tickets.
2. Planning to write a cover letter explaining my cycling achievements and providing them certificates of the same, which gives them Idea that my main purpose to visit is cycling.
3. Proving marriage ceritificate.
4. Giving the Hotel bookings and complete tour Itinerary.
5. Letters from Event organisers and cycling association in India.

Queries :

1. Should I include the refusal letter or just mention about it ?
2. While it is mentioned in checklist that I should give my travel details, bookings etc, in Guidance document, under section 4 I see that they are to be provided only if requested. So I'm confused, if that section 4 applies to general visitor VISA at all ?

Please advice me and help me go through the process.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a very common and straight-forward refusal. Please read the linked articles.  The guidance you should be using is here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents